# Erro de grafia em mensagem personalizada de fechamento

Tags: bug, tradução

Nessa pegunta, [Erro ASP.NET SecurityException: Request failed](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/423967/erro-asp-net-securityexception-request-failed), que foi fechada com motivo personalizado apareceu o seguinte quadro de fechamento:

> [image: Screenshot do quadro com problema ortográfico]

Se olhar com atenção no centro do quadro está escrito:

> Edite a pergunta para que esteja **[no escopo(/help/on-topic)** do Stack Overflow em Português.

A frase está com erro no link que está mal formado.

- Tem como consertar?
- Como que eu localizo essa string para que em outro bug eu mesmo possa fazer a correção?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Corrigi no [sistema de tradução colaborativa](https://pt.traducir.win), até amanhã deve atualizar no site.